# GridViewPager: Disable horizontal / veritcal scroll at times? (Android Wear)

Tags: android, wear-os

Basically Im looking for the behavior that comes with `WearableListView.setGreedyTouchMode(true)` -- but **without** the listview.

**Possible? How?**

Comment: Extends GridViewPager and override  GridViewPager#canScrollHorizontally() or canScrollVertically() and see if returning false would stop scrolling in those directions.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Thanks -- tried it and it doesnt change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I have a custom view that extends framelayout, which is shown on a grid view pager. Because framelayout is a ViewGroup I have access to requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent().

```
@Override
 public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(fixed);
     return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
 }
```

Where the fixed boolean is deciding weather to let the grid view pager take control or not.

Comment: I experimented with this too; although it disables all paging - I just want to disable one at a time.